# TYPO3: how to include other columns in section index?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a website with two columns (colPos = 0 and colPos = 2). Haw can I include headers from column 2 into the section index? The default behavior is to include only headers from column 0.

More specifically, here is the TypoScript I use to generate the menu:

```
lib.menupage = HMENU
lib.menupage {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul> | </ul>
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li> | </li>
    sectionIndex = 1
  }
}
```

I'm using TYPO3 6.0.

Comment: Your question can't be answered, as you even don't show us how are you using

Comment: I think he uses a content element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you are searching for

```
lib.menupage.1.sectionIndex.useColPos = -1
```

([But this seems to be only available in TYPO3 6.0](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Sectionindex/Index.html#menuobj-sectionindex))

As a workaround it should be possible to do it on your own. Render a normal menu, but override (allWrap.cObject should do the job) the link with an CONTENT Object, which retrieves all headers from tt_content of that page. Here is some pseudo-code which help to explain how i would try to solve that problem. This code will not work, just show the principle:

```
lib.menupage = HMENU
lib.menupage {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul> | </ul>
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li> | </li>
    # pgampe suggested to use: stdWrap2.append instead of allWrap.cObject. My intention
    # was to override the original link at all. But you should be able to play with
    # the different stdWrap functions to get the best solution
    # as far as i remember, allWrap will be wrapped by "wrapItemAndSub"
    NO.allWrap.cObject = CONTENT
    NO.allWrap.cObject {
       table = tt_content
       select {
         # the uid is the id of the page where we need the content from
         pidInList.field = uid
         orderBy = colPos, sorting
       }
       # inside the renderobj we get the elements which are retrieved by CONTENT
       renderObj = TEXT
       renderObj {
         field = header
         typolink.parameter.field = pid
         typolink.section.field = uid
         required = 1
         wrap = <span class="inside-li">|</span>
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking for the `section index` function in the `menu content object`.

The rendering is defined in `tt_content.menu.20.3.stdWrap.prepend.20 = CONTENT`. You can use the `TSOB (TypoScript Object Browser)` to investigate the relevant `typoscript` setup.

You can adjust it to your needs like any `CONTENT` object in TYPO3. However it should already select any column (at least in 6.0).

Comment: See the full example below.